# get Post fields and for each Post: details of last Comment

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel (v6), would like to get collection of matching Posts with *last* Comment.
Or, in my situation: matching Places, with details of *last* visit.

```
class Place extends Model
{
    public function visits(){
        return $this->hasMany(Timeline::class);
    }

    public function lastVisit(){
        return $this->visits()->orderBy('end', 'desc')->limit(1);
    }
...
```

This works fine for a single Place:

```
Place::where('id',2)->withCount('visits')->with('lastVisit')->get()
```

but for multiple Places it only shows the lastVisit for the **last** Place:

```
Place::where('name','like','%hotel%')->withCount('visits')->with('lastVisit')->get()
```

I also tried:

```
Place::where('name','like','%hotel%')
->withCount('visits')
->with(['visits' => function($e) {return $e->orderBy('end','desc')->first(); }])
->get()
```

This shows only the last Visit for the last Place, so: only one Visit in total.

When I leave out `->first()` each Place does include **all** Visits to that Place (sorted by last visit)

```
Place::where('name','like','%hotel%')
->withCount('visits')
->with(['visits' => function($e) {return $e->orderBy('end','desc'); }])
->get()
```

How do I get just the last Visit for each Place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `lastVisit` relationship a Has One:

```
public function lastVisit()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Timeline::class)->orderBy('end', 'desc');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Suggestions how to get only certain fields (including certain fields from the last visit)? Was hoping to use dot notation like: `Place::where('name','like','%hote%')->withCount('visits')->with('lastVisit') ->get() ->map(function($e) { return $e->only(['id','name','city','country','visits_count','lastVisit.end']); })`

Comment: `with('lastVisit:place_id,end')` .. just have to make sure to select the key needed for the relationship ... `$place->lastVisit->end`

Comment: ah, was missing the `place_id`. Thanks again!

Comment: yea any time you are going to limit what is selected for a relationship via this mechanism or eager loading constraints you have to make sure to select the keys needed to match up the relationship back to the parent or the other direction